# Comparar valores de uma array com values de um objeto

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo um simples código para praticar alguns métodos em JS, gostaria de receber uma string transforma-las em uma array, converter os elementos em número, e comparar com os objetos do meu objeto, vou deixar um trecho do código

```
 const alf = {a : 1,b : 2,c : 3,d : 4,e : 5,f : 6,g : 7,h : 8,i : 9,j : 10,k : 11,l : 12,m : 13,n : 14,o : 15,p : 16,q : 17,r : 18,s : 19,t : 20,w : 21,u : 22,v : 23,x : 24,y : 25,z : 26}

const Calcular = () => {
  elemResult = document.getElementById("resultado");
  str = document.getElementById("texto").value;
  str = str.toLowerCase().split("").map(p => {
    if(p in alf){
      return alf[p];
    }
  }).sort((a, b) => a-b).map(n => );
  elemResult.innerText = str;
}
```

Dentro do ultimo map, eu gostaria de converter os números novamente em string

Comment: Quando diz "converter os números novamente em String" é converter novamente nas letras com base no dicionário `alf` ?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode transformar o array em uma string utilizando o [`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) como no exemplo abaixo (o parâmetro é a string utilizada para separar os elementos na string, o valor default é `','`)

```js
const alf = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6, g: 7, h: 8, i: 9, j: 10, k: 11, l: 12, m: 13, n: 14, o: 15, p: 16, q: 17, r: 18, s: 19, t: 20, w: 21, u: 22, v: 23, x: 24, y: 25, z: 26 }

const Calcular = () => {
  elemResult = document.getElementById("resultado");
  str = document.getElementById("texto").value;
  str = str.toLowerCase().split("").map(p => {
    if (p in alf) {
      return alf[p];
    }
  }).sort((a, b) => a - b).join('');
  elemResult.innerText = str;
}

document.getElementById("texto").onblur = Calcular
```

```html
<input type="text" id="texto" />
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumindo que o seu converter os números novamente em String refere transforma-los de novo nas letras originais com base no número, pode utilizar o método [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) de array, partindo de um array de chaves com [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). Primeiro construímos uma função para obter a chave com base no valor:

```
const obterChave = (valor) => Object.keys(alf).find(key => alf[key] === valor);
```

Usei *Arrow Functions* também uma vez que estava a utilizar, o que torna o código mais consistente.

Depois apenas precisa de completar o `map` que deixou em aberto chamando esta função:

```
.sort((a, b) => a-b).map(n => obterChave(n));
```

Veja um exemplo desse código a funcionar:

```js
const alf = {a : 1,b : 2,c : 3,d : 4,e : 5,f : 6,g : 7,h : 8,i : 9,j : 10,k : 11,l : 12,m : 13,n : 14,o : 15,p : 16,q : 17,r : 18,s : 19,t : 20,w : 21,u : 22,v : 23,x : 24,y : 25,z : 26}
const obterChave = (valor) => Object.keys(alf).find(key => alf[key] === valor);
const texto = document.getElementById("texto");

const Calcular = () => {
  elemResult = document.getElementById("resultado");
  str = texto.value;
  str = str.toLowerCase().split("").map(p => {
    if(p in alf){
      return alf[p];
    }
  }).sort((a, b) => a-b).map(n => obterChave(n));
  elemResult.innerText = str;
}

texto.addEventListener("keypress", () => Calcular());
```

```html
Escreva um texto
<input type="text" id="texto">
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Mas o seu código acaba por mostrar as letras que estão no texto ordenadas se elas existirem no dicionário `alf`. Uma forma mais simples de fazer isso é ordenando as letras diretamente com `sort` e removendo as que não interessam com `filter`:

```js
const alf = {a : 1,b : 2,c : 3,d : 4,e : 5,f : 6,g : 7,h : 8,i : 9,j : 10,k : 11,l : 12,m : 13,n : 14,o : 15,p : 16,q : 17,r : 18,s : 19,t : 20,w : 21,u : 22,v : 23,x : 24,y : 25,z : 26}
const texto = document.getElementById("texto");

const Calcular = () => {
  elemResult = document.getElementById("resultado");
  str = texto.value.split("")
        .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)) //ordena por letra
        .filter(n => n in alf); //filtra só os que estão no dicionario
  elemResult.innerText = str;
}

texto.addEventListener("keypress", () => Calcular());
```

```html
Escreva um texto
<input type="text" id="texto">
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Assim não é necessário converter para número para ordenar e depois converter de volta para letra.